# Probability about lifetime of 100 bulbs (exponential distribution)

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, exponential-distribution

I have some doubts about the following problem:

I have 100 bulbs with a lifetime represented by an exponential distribution, with an expected value of 1000 hours. Find the probability that, at least one bulb, blown down after at most 500 hours.

I have calculated the probability about one bulb with this method:

$P(X \leq 500)=\int_{0}^{500}\lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx = 1-e^{\frac{1}{2}} = 0.394$

now, how can I extend this method for all the 100 bulbs? A step-by-step solution is really appreciated, I'm really newbie about statistics/probability arguments.

Thank you so much and best regards.

EDIT:
$\frac{1}{\lambda}=1000$ hours so $ \lambda = \frac{1}{1000} $

Comment: Just to be more precise $p=0.39347$. If you round this to 3 decimal digits we have approx $p=0.393$. But I would use the five decimal digits.

Comment: Yes, it was my mistake sorry... Have you any idea to extend the solution for $n$ bulbs? Now I have the probability about one bulb

Comment: Use the binomial distribution and the converse probability: $P(X\geq 1)=1-P(X=0)$, where $X\sim Bin(100, 0.39347)$. Here $n=100$ as given in the exercise. The solution is not very surprising.

Comment: Thanks callculus, tomorrow morning (where I am are 9 pm) I try to solve this exercise and write here if something goes wrong... only onother question, $P(X=0)$ is $1-0.393=0.606$?

Comment: As I understand it we have $1-p=0.607$. The probability that one bulb blow down after 500 hours. Then $P(X=0)=0.607^{100}\Rightarrow P(X\geq 1)=1-0.607^{100}\approx 1$

Comment: The probability that one bulb blow down is 0.39347 like in the integral in my request? 1-p is the probability that 99 works well or not?

Comment: The probability that one bulb blow down isn't 0.39347 like in the integral in my request?  You´re calculation was right. This is the probability of blowing down after at most 500 hour for **one** of the 100 bulbs  as I and Teddyboer understand it. But you have 99 other bulbs with the same probability of blowing down after at most 500 hours. The lifetimes of the 100 bulbs can be considered as 100 independent random variables with $p=0.393$. And so on...

Comment: Thanks callculus... at the end ths solution is a your past message right? So $P(X \leq 1)=1-0.607^{100}\approx 1$
I try a recap... 
$=0.39347$ the probability that one bulb blow down after at most 500 hours.
$q=1-p=0.607$ is the probability that all the bulbs works fine
$P(X \leq 1)=1-0.607^{100}\approx 1$ is the probability that at least one bulb, blown down after at most 500 hours.

Have I wrong something? I'm newbie and I wrong too much, sorry

Comment: I will sum these comments up: The probability that at least one bulb dies is $p=0.394$. So the probability that none of the $n=100$ bulbs dies ist $P(X=0)=(1-p)^{100}=0.607^{100}$. What you want is the probability that at least one dies, i.e. $P(X\geq1) = 1 - P(X=0) = 1 - 0.607^{100}$.

Comment: @BigUp Yes, hat´s how Teddyboer and I have understood the exercise.

Comment: Thanks a lot @callculus I have marked useful your answers (it's the only thing that I can do say thank you for your help)

Comment: Thank a lot @Teddyboer , I have marked useful your answers (it's the only thing that I can do say thank you for your help)
Stackexchange can tag one users per comment...

Comment: @BigUp You´re welcome. And thanks for marking some of my comments.

Comment: @callculus it's the minimum that I can do for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that it means "after at most 500 hours" right? In that case your computation makes sense for one bulb. What is $\lambda$ btw?

For the second part, we may assume that the bulbs are all independent and blow down within $500$ hours with a probability of $p=0.394$. You have $100$ bulbs. What is the chance that none of these blows down?

Comment: the statement is not so clear (is one of the problems of this), however I have assumed $\lambda = 1/1000$ and yes, "after at most 500 hours " is a perfect correction
About your question I can see that like the complement of 100% blows down? But I don't know how write this

Comment: Sorry, I overread the part where you say that the expected value is $1000$. I think the second part is simply a Bernoulli experiment with $n=100$ and $p=0.394$

Comment: Which quantity I must use for $q$? Or better to write $1-p$?

Comment: By $q$ you mean $q = 1-p$? Well then this.

Comment: Yes, $q=1-p$ so you mean 1-0.394=0.606? But this method answer to this question? "at least one bulb, blown down after at most 500 hours"

Comment: No not quite. As I mentioned before, it is a Bernoulli experiment with $n=100$. And you want the probability for $k=100$ fails ($q=0.606$ is the probability of $k=1$ fail). The answer is given by callculus above